# Using mock objects in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, jmock

Starting with *jMock* **2.6**, I can make sure my mock objects are seen consistently by multiple threads via

```
final Mockery mockery = new Mockery();
mockery.setThreadingPolicy(new Synchroniser());
```

What are my options (I'm experiencing intermittent test "flakes") when using *jMock* **2.5**?

Particularly, is it sufficient (**update**: no, doesn't play well with *expectations*) to wrap all mock object method invocations using `synchronized`?

```
<T> T synchronizedMock(final T mock,
        final Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
            new Class[] {clazz, CaptureControl.class},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                synchronized (mock) {
                    return method.invoke(mock, args);
                }
            });
}
```

When using the above approach, what are my chances to run into any deadlocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into using CGLib + ObjenesisHelper? CGLib will allow you to proxy both classes and interfaces instead of just interfaces like `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, and ObjenesisHelper will allow you to construct an instance of a class without having to invoke a constructor.
See [here for a CGLib example](http://www.coding-daddy.xyz/node/24) and [here for a ObjenesisHelper example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.objenesis.ObjenesisHelper).

Additionally you can unpack the `InvocationTargetException` to ensure that the proxy instance throws the expected `Exception` defined by the mocked class. Finally, using `registerStaticCallbacks` will ensure that the bound method interceptor is present among all invoking threads.

```
public <T> T createProxy(final Class<? extends T> classToMock, final T mock) {
    final MethodInterceptor interceptor = (object, method, args, proxy) -> {
        synchronized (mock) {
            try {
                return method.invoke(mock, args);
            } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
                if (e.getCause() != null) {
                    throw e.getCause();
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    };

    final Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(classToMock);
    final Set<Class<?>> interfaces = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    if (classToMock.isInterface()) {
        interfaces.add(classToMock);
    }
    interfaces.addAll(Arrays.asList(classToMock.getInterfaces()));
    interfaces.add(CaptureControl.class);
    enhancer.setInterfaces(interfaces.toArray(new Class[interfaces.size()]));
    enhancer.setCallbackType(interceptor.getClass());

    final Class<?> proxyClass = enhancer.createClass();
    Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(proxyClass, new Callback[] { interceptor });
    return (T) ObjenesisHelper.newInstance(proxyClass);
}
```

> When using the above approach, what are my chances to run into any deadlocks?

I do not believe the solution you provided, nor the suggested solution above should run into any deadlocks *(assuming that there are no deadlocks already present in your code)*. The use of `synchronized` will ensure that only one thread will can manipulate the mock instance at any given time.. and unless jmock delegates method invocation to a separate thread *(which to my knowledge it does not)* then the code should execute normally and not block. If jmock requires you lock on all `Mockery` instances at once then you could pass in a dedicated object to synchronize on, or provide a Re-entrant lock for all proxy interceptors to share.

Comment: While this still doesn't solve my problem with expectations which keep failing, thank you for your answer anyway.

BTW, I've edited your code sample a little: the list of interfaces mustn't be empty, or `enhancer.setInterfaces()` shouldn't be called at all. Additionally, `CaptureControl` should be in the list of interfaces mocked, otherwise _jMock_ will refuse to set any expectations.